# Sorting a list of strings items from an array

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to python automation and wrote a script to get some port handles from Ixia and store into a list. I;m trynig to sort that port-handle where I see a problem.

I tried using the sort method but doesn;t work

```
>>> a
['1/1/11', '1/1/6']
>>> a.sort()
>>> a
['1/1/11', '1/1/6']
>>> d = a.sort()
>>> print(d)
None
>>>
```

Am i missing anything here .. kindly clarify

I want the output in the following format

```
1/1/6 1/1/11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Explanation

You are trying to sort a list of **strings**. **Strings** are naturally sorted in [lexicographical_order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order), i.e. `"10" < "11" < "2" < "5" < ...`, so **Python** executes correctly what you want it to do. This being said, you need to transform your data into something that will be sorted as you want.

## Solution

```py
>>> a = ['1/1/11', '1/1/6']
>>> a
['1/1/11', '1/1/6']
>>> def to_tuple(string_representation):
...     return tuple(int(i) for i in string_representation.split('/'))
... 
>>> b = [to_tuple(element) for element in a]
>>> b.sort()
>>> b
[(1, 1, 6), (1, 1, 11)]
>>> a.sort(key=to_tuple)
>>> a
['1/1/6', '1/1/11']
```

Here we use the fact that [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple) is sorted by default exactly how we want it to be sorted in your case (actually, it is also a lexicographical order, but now `11` is one element of a sequence and not two).

List `b` contains a transformed list, where each element is a `tuple`. And now `sort` will work as you want.

The second option, will be using a custom `key` operator. It is a function that returns a key to compare different elements of your list. In this case, key will be a corresponding `tuple` of integers and will be compared as you want.

## Note 1

The second approach (with the `key` operator) will create an additional overhead during sorting as it will be called `O(NlogN)` times.

## Note 2

You also tried using the result of `sort` function as a value, but it changes the given list *in-place*. If you want a sorted copy of your list, use [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted).